# short and quick way to compare the last line in 2 different files in bash?

Tags: bash

I have 2 files and I would like to check if the last line of each is the same.

I thought that I could tail each file, save the output in a variable and compare this variable, so I know if the last line is the same in both files.

Is this the correct way to do so, or there is a magic one line command that avoid to go trough all these hoops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```
[[ "$(tail -1 file1)" == "$(tail -1 file2)" ]] && echo "same" || echo "not same"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know that I can compare command output without put the output in a variable first!